# How do I count Customers without Orders?

Tags: mysql

I have a User table and a Order table in my MySQL database. One user can have many orders.

I'm trying to find the number of **users that have never placed an order**, and have tried variations of this:

```
// Incorrect query
SELECT count(u.id)
FROM user AS u
WHERE count(u.o) = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN order AS o
ON o.user_id = u.id
;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you include the table structures in the question or create a SQL fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM order);
```

This is simple and effective; it gives you all `id` from `user` which aren't in `order` (i.e. have never placed one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
as:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USER
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT USER_ID FROM ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using `left join`:

```
SELECT count(u.id)
FROM user AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN order AS o
    ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.user_id IS NOT NULL
```